# Why can my library not access its resources?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, classloader, packaging

I have a class that reads a file:

```
package classlibrary;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class ReadingResource {
    public static String readResource() throws IOException {
        URL resource = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("classlibrary/test_file.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(resource.getPath()));
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

The resource file is in the same directory where this class is.
I made a library out of this class and the file.

Now I want to use it in the other class:

```
package uritesting;

import classlibrary.ReadingResource;
import java.io.IOException;

public class URITesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(ReadingResource.readResource());
    }
}
```

When I make a .jar file out of this class, set the class as the main class, add the .jar from above and execute it as "java -jar URITesting.jar" I get a FileNotFoundException, saying the class `ReadingResource` can not find the specified file. It is funny because the path that is specified in the exception message is actually the correct path to the file.

You can find the files [here](http://goo.gl/AHY99F).

**EDIT:**
I developed the project in NetBeans. When I run it there, it works fine. The classpath is different in that case. It contains both resources of the `URITestingProject` and `ReadingResource`.

However, when I run it as a standalone JAR, the classpath contains `URITestingProject` only. What is strange to me is that it doesn't complain about not finding the class `ReadingResource`. It means that it is loaded, although it is not in the classpath :/

Comment: there is no `test_file.txt` in the `URITesting.jar`. Do you mean the ClassLibraryTest.jar?

Comment: Yes, I mean ClassLibraryTest.jar. The method `ReadingResource.readResource()` is supposed to look for the `test_file.txt` file in its own resources, i.e., in ClassLibraryTest.jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `resource.getPath()`. It's not possible to calculate a path ,valid for a file reader, inside a jar file, on another server and so on. However you can get the data through a stream instead:

```
    InputStream data = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("classlibrary/test_file.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(data, "utf-8"));
```

As a side note: When reading with reader it's a good idea to specify the encoding: